# Вставить несколько строк в mysql по php

Tags: php, mysql

Как передать массивные данные из формы в mysql - одним Запросом? И чтобы данные каждого цикла, были добавлены в отдельную строку в таблице БД. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробую так:
**Цикл input-ов откуда передаются данные**

```
while($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($rsm)) {
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="visited[]">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id[]" value="'.$myrow['user_id'].'">
    <input type="hidden" name="day[]" value="'.$textday.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="dates[]" value="'.$today.'">
}
```

INSERT

```
foreach($_POST[visited] as $visited){

$sql= mysql_query ("INSERT into dates (user_id,dates,visited) Values ($user_id,$dates,$visited)");
}
```

Comment: Вот пробуете вы и что получаете? Какие ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу реализацию на вышем примере, а вообще советую перейти на PDO подход, и как то фильтровать данные перед тем как вставить в запрос.

К примеру ваш POST запрос выглядел бы вот так:

```
$_POST = [
    'visited' => [
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    'user_id' => [
        20,
        30,
        30
    ],
    'dates' => [
        '12-12-2015',
        '12-12-2016',
        '12-12-2017',
    ]
];
```

Чтобы его сохранить достаточно этого кода:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO dates (user_id,dates,visited) VALUES ';
$values_array = [];
foreach ($_POST['visited'] as $key => $visited) {
    $values_array[] = sprintf("('%s', '%s', '%s')", $_POST['user_id'][$key], $_POST['dates'][$key], $visited); //Лучше заменить '%d', '%s', '%d' но я не знаю как лежат у вас данные, так что этот вариант чтобы наверняка
}

$values_string = implode(', ', $values_array);

$query .= $values_string;

$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

В итоге в переменной `$query` лежит вот такая строка:

```
string(128) "INSERT INTO dates (user_id,dates,visited) VALUES ('20', '12-12-2015', '1'), ('30', '12-12-2016', '1'), ('30', '12-12-2017', '1')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сформировать SQL-запрос, который вставит сразу несколько строк в таблицу. В MySQL этот запрос обычно имеет следующий вид:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4);
```

, где a, b, c - имена полей, в которые нужно вставить значения, а данные в каждой паре круглых скобок соответственно значения этих полей. Одни скобки - одна вставленная строка.

Для того, чтобы сформировать запрос для вашего случая, нужно сделать так:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO dates (user_id, dates, visited) VALUES ';
foreach($_POST[visited] as $visited) {
    $sql .= '($user_id, $dates, $visited),';
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
mysql_query($sql);
```

Обращаю огромнейшее внимание на то, что у вас не проверяются вводимые пользователем данные, из-за чего любой пользователь сможет применить SQL-инъекцию и выполнить практически любой запрос. Но это не касается темы вашего вопроса, поэтому я это и не исправлял - советую перейти на PDO и почитать про SQL-инъекции.